# How to publish manually created WebJobs to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs

I created a WebJobs app targeting .NET Core following this article: http://matt-roberts.me/azure-webjobs-in-net-core-2-with-di-and-configuration/

I had to do this manually because currently Visual Studio does not provide a way to create a `WebJobs` app in `.NET Core` but I can create a console app targeting `.NET Core` in Visual Studio 2017.

Now, I want to publish my `WebJobs` console app to Azure but I'm NOT getting the option to `Publish as Azure WebJob` which Visual Studio typically gives -- see below:
[image]

Instead, I'm just getting "Publish" option and not sure if this will work as intended.

How do I publish my manually created `WebJobs` console app to Azure as a `WebJob`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always publish WebJobs manually. There are several ways:

- Directly copy the relevant files into `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\{job name}` (e.g. using Kudu Console)
- Zip up all the files and upload it as a continuous WebJob using the Azure Portal

Also, for the WebJobs engine to know how to run your Core app, you will need to include a `run.cmd` file that runs it (place that file in the same folder). e.g. it should contain something like `dotnet YouWebJobAssembly.dll`, or whatever command line you want to use to start it.

Comment: I assume I need to zip up files in `\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0` folder, correct? Also, only the `DLL` files or `json` files too? I see `myapp.deps.json`, `myapp.runtimeconfig.json` files as well.

Comment: You need to include whatever makes up your app. e.g. if you were to run this app locally from some random folder, you'd have a set of files. That same set is what you need. The WebJobs engine has no specific knowledge of your app layout. It will just run the executable and it will do what it does.

Comment: I also just added info about including a `run.cmd`.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm now getting an error that states that An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found: package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions', version: '1.1.0'. Looks like this approach is not handling the assemblies that are installed with NuGet packages. I don't see any of them in the `bin` folder though.

Comment: Try to isolate by running it directly from Kudu console. This way it's no longer a WebJobs issue

Comment: Looks like .NET Core 2.0 app may not copy assemblies that the app depends on. I added `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to `csproj` file which actually worked and copied all the necessary assemblies BUT now I'm getting an error on WebJobs console telling me that package: 'System.Data.SqlClient', version: '4.4.2' was not found. The `SqlClient.dll` is there but if I right click the file and check version, it's showig 4.6. I don't know why Visual Studio would copy the wrong version of this `DLL`. In `csproj` file, the version number is the correct one. Frustrating!

Comment: That's sounds like a separate question about how to build your app in general, and not related to WebJobs in particular. I suggest a new question to tackle this.

Comment: I see you posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040013/net-core-2-console-app-dependencies-issue-on-azure and got that part resolved!

Comment: Yes, thanks. Made me remember how much I appreciate UI based solutions. Sometimes getting into the nitty gritty is fun. Other times it's like seeing the guy take off the Goofy costume at Disney! It can scar you for life :-)

Comment: @Sam interesting analogy :)