# .NET Core 2 Console App Dependencies Issue on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, console-application, azure-webjobs, .net-core-2.0

**Short version of the problem:**

I'm having difficulties including the assemblies my .NET Core Console App depends on.

Initially, the assemblies from NuGet packages were not included in the `bin` folder even though I could run the app in `Debug` mode without any problems.

Found an article that suggested that I should add `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` in the `myapp.csproj` file which I did.

Doing so included the `dll` files for the NuGet packages in the `bin` folder BUT after I copied my console app to Azure to run as a WebJob, I got an error telling me that `System.Data.SqlClient` was missing.

After inspecting the folder where the WebJob runs, I could see that the `dll` for `System.Data.SqlClient` is actually in the folder. I concluded that it may have been an issue with version numbers. The error indicated the following:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient', version: '4.4.2' was not found

When I right click the `dll` file for this assembly and check its version, it shows version 4.6.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

**Longer Version:**

I built this .NET Core 2.0 console app to run as a WebJob following this article: http://matt-roberts.me/azure-webjobs-in-net-core-2-with-di-and-configuration/

I had to create this WebJobs app manually because currently Visual Studio does not provide a way to build Azure WebJobs in .NET Core.

Because of this current limitation, I also could not Publish my WebJobs app directly from Visual Studio.

So, I tried to zip it up and upload it through Azure Portal. This is when I realized that NuGet assemblies were not included in the `bin` folder. The rest of the story is already up in the "Short Version" section.

I'd appreciate some suggestion in solving this issue.

**UPDATE:**

When I ran `dotnet publish --self-contained -r win32-x64 -c Release` inside the project's root folder, I got the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure of the WebJobs specification, but you should be able to use `dotnet publish --self-contained -r win-x64 -c Release` to generate executable and its dependencies. Zip them up and you should be able to deploy to Azure.

There is really no need to modify your `csproj` like you did.

Besides, you can use .NET IL Linker to shrink the size of the generated folder.

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment-with-third-party-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work. Getting Project is targeting runtime 'win32-x64' but did not resolve any runtime-specific packages for the 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' package.  This runtime may not be supported by .NET Core. error. Put a screen shot in original post.

Comment: Updated and added the reference. You need to specify `RuntimeIdentifiers`.

Comment: Still doesn't like it. Added `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` in the `PropertyGroup` that contains `TargetFramework` and `OutputType`. Then issued `dotnet publish --self-contained -r win32-x64 -c Release` in the root of the project as well as the one level up where the `csproj` file is but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Sam get started from an empty project as the article indicates first.

Comment: I made a mistake by saying `win32-x64`. It should be `win-x64` if you check the reference.

Comment: This worked! I wasn't crazy about creating a fresh new copy of my app but I did and `dotnet publish --self-contained -r win-x64 -c Release` created a nice `Publish` folder with all the necessary assemblies in it. I uploaded it to Azure and now it's running nicely. Thank you very much!