# .NET Core Runtime

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, .net-core-2.0, runtime-identifier

If I want to create .NET Core 2.0 apps e.g. Console App or ASP.NET Core 2.0, what .NET runtimes do I need installed on my dev machine? I'm on Windows 10.

I created a .NET Core 2.0 Console app to run as a WebJob. In order to zip it up and upload it to Azure, I followed this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment-with-third-party-dependencies

When I ran `dotnet publish --self-contained -r win32-x64 -c Release` I got an error that reads:

> Microsoft.NETCore.App.targets(19,5): error : Project is targeting
>   runtime 'win32-x64' but did not resolve any runtime-specific packages
>   for the 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' package.  This runtime may not be
>   supported by .NET Core.

But if I run `dotnet publish --self-contained -r win10-x64 -c Release`, it works fine.

Just want to make sure I'm preparing my app the right way for Azure.

Also I'd like to run my app as 64 Bit, not 32.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core 2 Console App Dependencies Issue on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040013/net-core-2-console-app-dependencies-issue-on-azure)

Comment: You don't need to open a new question. I simply made a mistake in my previous answer.

Comment: Thank you but I think this is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`win32-x64` is not a valid runtime identifier. Use `win-x64` instead or see the [.NET Core RID Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids) for a list of valid runtime identifiers.