# Azure WebJobs with DLL: upload fails

Tags: .net, vb.net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have written a console application.  This app has a number of references to external libraries (some are .Net libraries and some are custom libraries).  When I build the app, it includes a number of DLLs.  I then zip this file and try to upload it to Azure WebJobs but the upload fails.  If I remove all of the DLL files from the zip file, it will upload just fine (but can't run do to the missing DLL files).  Also, if I try to upload just a DLL file, I get an error saying:

```
File extension for Json.Net.dll is not present in the allowed file extensions list - "cmd,bat,exe,ps1,sh,php,py,js,jar,zip"
```

It seems WebJobs blocks DLL files.  How do I create a WebJob if it requires DLL files?  My Azure admin says if there is an approval list to allow these file types; they can add the extension but they don't see a way to do so.  Is this something that can be added in Azure?

Comment: Did you try publishing it from visual studio? I just made a dummy app and deployed from visual studio directly. seems like it has a lot of dll files and working fine

Comment: No, I deploy by zipping the files and uploading in Azure.  I use to not have an issue with this. But in the last month or so, Azure seems to have started blocking these file types

Comment: When you say "uploading in Azure": what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I open my app service.  I then go to the WebJobs tab.  I click the "Add" button.  This provides fields to upload file (zip as well) and setup and configure your web job

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037011/how-to-publish-manually-created-webjobs-to-azure

Comment: I ended up publishing from Visual Studio and its fine.  I am just wondering why you can no longer do it right from Azure?  I use to be able to?  I guess it doesn't matter if it works going through Visual Studio.  Its just my Azure admin probably thinks i'm crazy lol

Comment: But, after setting up deployment via Visual Studio, I now get an error that pops up every 5 minutes or so.  It says "Certificate: Revocation Status: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline."

Comment: @jason, if the answer below is helpful, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure webjobs definitely supports the zip file contains .dll file, I just have a test at my side, upload a zip file which contains .dll files. And it can be uploads to azure webjobs and works well.

Maybe there are some problems with your azure environment, you'd better submit a support ticket to the azure team, by following [this steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

The screenshot below is the zip file at my side.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it is certainly an issue with our Azure environment.  But, our CIO manages it and they don't know how to fix it.  So, I just went the route of publishing right from Visual Studio.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes i faced the same issues while upload the .zip files to webjob and managed the with uploading with visual studio.